# Python installation messed up

Tags: python

Somehow my python on my Mac OS X is messed up.

I am trying to install `virtualenv`

```
$ pip install virtualenv
```

And it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.40-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 16, in <module>
    import sys, os, zipimport, time, re, imp, types
ImportError: No module named time
```

However if I try it like this, it finds `time`.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>>
```

My path variable looks like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/opengeo/pgsql/9.1/bin
```

Could it be that my path variable is set wrong? Where and how can I fix this?

Comment: You could look into the Anaconda distribution of Python from Continuum IO if you want. It's a pretty decent distro packed with a bunch of libraries, and it just works. No need to personally manage libraries anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using multiple versions of Python simultaneously - one from Python.org (2.7.3), located in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/`, which does not have an installation of `pip` associated with it, and another version from HomeBrew (2.7.5), located in `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/`. Your `pip` script is using the `/usr/local/...` Python, which doesn't have the `time` module available for some reason, but when you just type `python` on the command line, the shell searches through your `$PATH` and runs the version in `/Library/Frameworks/...`. If you were to type `/usr/local/bin/python` on the command line and enter `import time` you will likely get an error. [The `time` module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html) is part of the Python standard library, so I'm not sure why homebrew isn't finding it - you might want to re-brew python to fix it.

To always run the homebrew version of python (if that's what you want your primary version to be), just put `/usr/local/bin` as the first entry in your `$PATH` variable.